# To wait to an object frame doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wait for a iframe loading with jQuery but every time when I try

```
$(window.frames[0]).load
```

doesn't work on Firefox, but it does on Safari. If I use

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

it works.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: what does not work? is the iframe not ready yet immediately after the load() statement? Or does it not load altogether?

Comment: @flup Well, I'm trying to do whatever after the load of the iframe, and I'm trying to do it with that function but it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, try:

```
$(window.frames).eq(0).load(function () { ... });
```

I have not tested this code.